# How to save file that was made by program on Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, heroku-cli

I'm just starting to use Heroku for my program. But I have a problem.
Every time I'm making a commit by Heroku Git clears all files which were made by my program
I'm not rewriting them by commit
Sorry, I don't know how to explain my problem properly, ask any questions you need

Comment: I know that it is'n a good thing to do (making files by my program i mean) and that i should use db for this case. But my project is really small and nothing bad could happen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%5Bheroku%5D+ephemeral+filesystem

Comment: Any external storage — database, S3, etc.